# Make shorter filtering of a df with boolean output

Tags: python, filtering, data-manipulation

I feel like that it is possible to make this statement shorter but I haven't realized how...

```py
a = []
for i in df['Age'].values:
    if i > 40:
        a.append(True)
    else:
        a.append(False)
df['over 40?'] = a
```

Comment: Please add language tag.
I'm guessing this is Python?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily write the following lines:

```py
a=[]
for i in df['Age'].values:
    a.append(i>40)

df['over 40?']=a
```

Or if you want to use the [map function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda), you can also write:

```py
df['over 40?']=map(lambda i: i > 40, df['Age'].values)
```